# Checking permission for files

Tags: command-line, command

Is there any way to check/find files and directories that **only I created** and check their permission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To list all the files out in this manner you can use the tool `find`, along with the switches `-user <username>` and either `-ls` to get a standard type of `ls` output, or you can control it more specifically, using the `-printf` switch, telling it which columns, and in what order you want them.

```
$ find /path/to -user <username> -ls
```

#### Example

```
$ find . -user saml -ls
6553601   24 drwx------ 170 saml     saml        20480 Oct 31 20:55 .
6556571    4 -rw-rw-r--   1 saml     saml         1641 Jul 11 20:53 ./.gitk
6554851    4 -rwxrwxr-x   1 saml     saml          738 May 22 13:31 ./dmesg_time.pl
8542099    4 drwxrwxr-x   2 saml     saml         4096 Sep 27 08:08 ./.streamCapture
8542100    4 -rw-rw-r--   1 saml     saml          113 Sep 27 08:10 ./.streamCapture/streamCapture.conf
8792905    4 drwxrwxr-x   6 saml     saml         4096 Mar  5  2014 ./Release
```

Comment: Hey, a little follow up question: 

What if I want to see If I have full acces in those directories that I created and other just can read?

Would I need to add to the search `-perm 744`?

Comment: The example I gave you lists both files + dirs. You can limit it to directories with `-type d`. To see dirs. w/ specific permissions, yes you'd use `-perm <#>`.